# Why does my system (w/ btrfs, hourly snapshots) "lock up" when cloning large repo or copying many files

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs, storage

Here's my situation.  I use btrfs and snapper for its snapshot'ing capabilities.  I take hourly snapshots of my work directory and the feature (`cd .snapshots/hourly.2` then copying back old work) has saved my a** a hundred times over.  I choose not to live without this feature for my workstation and "can't afford" a NetApp filler :(

Every so often, I'll need to clone a large git repository (e.g., gcc or Linux kernel).  My system freezes almost initially after I initiate the clone.  I can move the mouse around but that's about it, switch desktops, launch programs, etc.  I cannot Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a text mode shell.

After some time, on the order of 10+++ mins, the system will unfreeze.

I understand that this is not a lot to go on but I am hoping that someone can help me.

Another question is, should I be looking at other technologies to replicate hourly snapshotting functionality?  Should the snapshots be copied over to a second disk?  Is there a better way?

Comment: I strongly suspect this :https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Fragmentation